# Display User Profile getting ERROR: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-forms

- **I have a simple view that is suppose to check if there is post data,
  if so update the user data using `UserChangeForm`. Else get the form
  data of user and display.**

> Issue: AttributeError at /profile/edit 'AnonymousUser' object has no
>   attribute '_meta'

I think it might be this line in the `edit_profile` view

```
    # Handles the get request - if no post info is submitted then get the form and display it on the edit profile page. 
else:
    form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', args)
```

**Not sure what. Here is the `view.py edit_profile`**

```
def edit_profile(request):
 # Handle post request - if the user submits a form change form details and pass the intance user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, intance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('accounts/profile')
# Handles the get request - if no post info is submitted then get the form and display it on the edit profile page. 
else:
    form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', args)
```

**profile_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Profile</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: and are you logged in??

Comment: Omg. Yep, that's it - still learning :'(

Comment: mistakes will make you learn better ;)

Comment: You are not logged in. This way showing  AnonymousUser error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update an `AnnonymousUser` (that is special user class set for not logged in users). One solution of your problem is to disallow viewing this page by not authenticated user by decorating your view using [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You got error because there is not user logged in.
You can instead use try method.

In your code use if user.is_authenticated

```
if user.is_authenticated():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, intance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('accounts/profile')
# Handles the get request - if no post info is submitted then get the form and display it on the edit profile page. 
    else:
      form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
      args = {'form': form}
      return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', args)
else:
    raise PermissionDenied
```